# Google Chart Set Columns with line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Advanced Thanks. Pretty simple, I checked the chart API guide / posts on here, but I cannot get it to work.  I am trying to set Google Charts to display the first two columns in my line Chart. As the third column I use to filter the results that appear using a `CategoryFilter`

`view: {'columns': [0,1]}` I know I need to be using this code, but I am not sure where, I tried it in the options but with no luck?

Columns: I want to plot Date, Species, which works, however currently it also plots the site too.

```
Date,     Species, Site
12-6-2010,  1,      49




    // Create a line chart, passing some options
    var LineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'LineChart',
      'containerId': 'chart_div',

      'options': {
        //'width': 600,
        'height': 600,
        //'pieSliceText': 'value',
        'legend': 'top'

      }
       // 'view':{'columns':[0,1]}
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the code above, there is a comma missing from the end of the options {}. List items should all end with a comma, apart from the last one. Here you had two items without a comma :-)

```
 'options': {
    //'width': 600,
    'height': 600,
    //'pieSliceText': 'value',
    'legend': 'top'
  },
   'view':{'columns':[0,1]}
});
```